# DynamoDB costs arising due to triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a workflow where I put files into an S3 bucket, which triggers a Lambda function. The Lambda function extracts some info about the file and inserts a row into a DynamoDB table for each file:

```
def put_filename_in_db(dynamodb, filekey, filename):
    table = dynamodb.Table(dynamodb_table_name)
    try:
        response = table.put_item(
            Item={
            'masterclient': masterclient,
            'filekey': filekey,
            'filename': filename,
            'filetype': filetype,
            'source_bucket_name': source_bucket_name,
            'unixtimestamp': unixtimestamp,
            'processed_on': None,
            'archive_path': None,
            'archived_on': None,
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Error") 
    return response

def get_files():
    bucket_content = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=str(source_bucket_name), Prefix=Incoming_prefix)['Contents']  
    file_list = []

    for k, v in enumerate(bucket_content):
        if (v['Key'].endswith("zip") and not v['Key'].startswith(Archive_prefix)):
            filekey = v['Key']
            filename = ...  

            dict = {"filekey": filekey, "filename": filename}
            file_list.append(dict)

    logger.info(f'Found {len(file_list)} files to process: {file_list}')
    return file_list

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for current_item in get_files():
        filekey = current_item['filekey']
        filename = current_item['filename']      
        put_filename_in_db(dynamodb, filekey, filename)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

This is how my DynamoDB table is defined in terraform:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "filenames" {
  name           = local.dynamodb_table_filenames
  billing_mode   = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  #read_capacity  = 10
  #write_capacity = 10
  hash_key       = "filename"
  stream_enabled = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_IMAGE"
  attribute {
    name = "filename"
    type = "S"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "allow_dynamodb_table_to_trigger_lambda" {
  event_source_arn  = aws_dynamodb_table.filenames.stream_arn
  function_name     = aws_lambda_function.trigger_stepfunction_lambda.arn
  starting_position = "LATEST"
}
```

New entries in the DynamoDB table trigger another Lambda function which contains this:

```
def parse_file_info_from_trigger(event):
    filename = event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['Keys']['filename']['S']
    filetype = event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['NewImage']['filetype']['S']
    unixtimestamp = event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['NewImage']['unixtimestamp']['S']
    masterclient = event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['NewImage']['masterclient']['S']
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['NewImage']['source_bucket_name']['S']
    filekey = event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['NewImage']['filekey']['S']

    return filename, filetype, unixtimestamp, masterclient, source_bucket_name, filekey


def start_step_function(event, state_machine_zip_files_arn):
    if event['Records'][0]['eventName'] == 'INSERT':
            filename, filetype, unixtimestamp, masterclient, source_bucket_name, filekey = parse_file_info_from_trigger(event)
    ......
    else: 
        logger.info(f'This is not an Insert event')
```

However, the costs for this process are extremely high. If I start testing with a single file loaded into S3, the overall DynamoDB costs for that day were $0.785. If I do it for around 50 files for a day, that would mean my total costs per day are 40$, which seems too high if we want to run the workflow on a daily basis.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is DynamoDB generally expensive? If it's the later, then what part exactly is costing so much? Or is it because  `put_filename_in_db` is running in a loop?

[image]

Comment: Sounds high so you're probably missing something significant. Maybe you have high provisioned concurrency or a large table? DynamoDB pricing is a combination of requests, storage, and table capacity. Check what your table config looks like (e.g. is it on-demand capacity?) and use the AWS calculator to get an estimate. Also, you need to check what's actually happening with your code e.g. how often it's actually executing. Writes cost something like $1.56 per million 1KB writes for on-demand. Storage costs are $0.25 per GB-month, after the first 25GB stored per month which is free.

Comment: the billing mode is pay per request. i have added the terraform code which shows the config of the dynamo db table. could you take a look? i also added my code of how the i put info into my dynamo db table. while testing, initially it was empty and then i added a row. and then the costs were as i mentioned above @jarmod

Comment: I'd recommend reviewing the [metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html) for your table(s). See what is really happening.

Comment: what exactly should I look for here? Under operations, I see putItem, updateItem, and Scan only. Nothing looks unusual @jarmod Can you see the screenshot in the updated qs? Does it tell you anything?

Comment: For the 24 hour period that you say cost $0.785, what were the API request counts? What was the approximate size of the table? How sure are you about that cost? How did it compare to the cost on subsequent days?